# How can I calculate the adjoint of the wave operator $\square_{g}$ in $H^{k}$?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes

I have a three part question, which I could only received an answer for the first part [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1227753/what-is-the-adjoint-of-the-wave-operator-square-g-in-sobolev-spaces).

1. The [Laplace-Beltrami](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace%E2%80%93Beltrami_operator) operator is an operator which is the typical example of a self-adjoint operator in $L^{2}$. I am wondering if this is also true for other Hilbert spaces $H^{k}$.
2. The second part of the question and in which I am more interested is the following: How much the results are true for metrics with are not positive definitive. For example, the [D'Alambertian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%27Alembert_operator)(wave operator) in a general Pseudo-riemannian space.
3. Below I am trying to calculate explicitly the adjoint for $\square_{g}$ in $H^{1}({{\cal{U}}_{t_{1}}^{+}},\nu_{g}=\sqrt{-g}d^{4}x)$. Any comments will be appreciated.

The wave operator is self-adjoint in $L^{2}({{\cal{U}}_{t_{1}}^{+}},\nu_{g})$ which means that for all $\psi,\omega \in C_{c}^{\infty}({{\cal{U}}_{t_{1}}^{+}})$ it is true that:
$$(\psi,\square\omega)_{L^2}=(\square\psi,\omega)_{L^2}$$.

which allow us to write:

$$\int_{{{\cal{U}}_{t_{1}}^{+}}} \square_{g}\psi\omega \nu_{g}
=
\int_{{{\cal{U}}_{t_{1}}^{+}}} \psi\square_{g}\omega \nu_{g}$$

Now taking into account the contracted Ricci identity:

$$\square(\psi_{,i})=(\square\psi)_{,i}+R^{j}_{i}\psi_{,j}$$

we have the following equality:

$$
\int_{{{\cal{U}}_{t_{1}}^{+}}} (\square_{g}\psi)_{,i}\omega_{,i} \nu_{g}
=
\int_{{{\cal{U}}_{t_{1}}^{+}}} (\square_{g}(\psi_{,i})-R^{j}_{i}\psi_{,j})\omega_{,i}  \nu_{g}
$$

Now the first term using the self adjointness of $\square_{g}$ can be rewritten as:
$$
\int_{{{\cal{U}}_{t_{1}}^{+}}}\square_{g}(\psi_{,i})\omega_{,i} \nu_{g}
=
\int_{{{\cal{U}}_{t_{1}}^{+}}} \psi_{,_{i}}\square_{g}(\omega_{,i}) \nu_{g}
$$
which again using the contracted Ricci identities gives:
$$
\int_{{{\cal{U}}_{t_{1}}^{+}}}\psi_{,_{i}}\square_{g}(\omega_{,i}) \nu_{g}
=
\int_{{{\cal{U}}_{t_{1}}^{+}}} \psi_{,_{i}}((\square_{g}\omega)_{,i}+R^{j}_{i}\omega_{,j}) \nu_{g}
$$

Now putting together the above equalities we have that:

$$
  \int_{{{\cal{U}}_{t_{1}}^{+}}}\square\psi\omega \nu_{g}+ \int_{{{\cal{U}}_{t_{1}}^{+}}}(\square\psi)_{i}\omega_{i} \nu_{g}=\int_{{{\cal{U}}_{t_{1}}^{+}}}\psi\square\omega \nu_{g}+ \int_{{{\cal{U}}_{t_{1}}^{+}}}\psi_{i}(\square\omega)_{i} \nu_{g}+\int_{{{\cal{U}}_{t_{1}}^{+}}}(R^{i}_{j}-R^{j}_{i})\psi_{,j}\omega_{,i}   \nu_{g}
$$

It seems that in the case $R^{i}_{j}=0$ then the $\square_{g}$ is self adjoint.
Is that correct?

So to sum up.

My **main question** is:

How can I calculate the adjoint of the wave operator $\square_{g}$ in Sobolev Spaces?

Comment: Just a few remarks: the Laplace-Beltrami operator $\Box_g$ on a *Riemannian* manifold $(M,g)$ is essentially self-adjoint with domain of smooth $p$-forms with compact support when $(M,g)$ is complete (particularly when $M$ is compact), as shown by Chernoff, Strichartz and other people. In complete generality, $\Box_g$ has at least one self-adjoint extension - namely, the Friedrichs extension, since the quadratic form associated to $\Box_g$ is *bounded from below*. The latter property is lost when $g$ is not positive definite. All we can say then is that $\Box_g$ is symmetric.

Comment: Computing the adjoint of an unbounded operator such as $\Box_g$ involves not only finding its formula, but also its domain from that of $\Box_g$. It's not clear from your reasoning which is the domain you assume for $\Box_g$ - notice that it cannot be the whole Hilbert space, be it $L^2$ of $H^k$. If you assume, as in my former comment, its domain to be smooth forms of compact support, then the symmetry of $\Box_g$ follows immediately from the definition, since $\Box_g=d\delta+\delta d$, where the co-differential $\delta$ is the formal adjoint of $d$.

Comment: In other words, the *formal* adjoint of $\Box_g$ (i.e. the restriction of the adjoint of $\Box_g$ to the latter's domain) is equal to $\Box_g$ itself.

Comment: By the way, what is your definition of $\mathcal{U}^+_t$?

Comment: Thank you for you comments. ${{\cal{U}}_{t_{1}}^{+}}$ is just any open set with compact closure on a manifold $M$. Is the comment you make about symmetry of $\square_{g}$ that follows from the definition using the differential and the codifferential applies in $H^{k}$ or only in L2?

Comment: It applies to both, since the domain of $\Box_g$ is assumed to be the (dense in both) linear subspace of smooth functions / forms with compact support. Again, $\Box_g$ is not defined as a linear operator from either Hilbert space into itself.

Comment: I apologize, actually smooth functions / forms of compact support are dense only in $L^2$ for the region you specified. For $H^k$ you need to specify another dense domain - a possibility would be to choose smooth functions / forms in $H^k$ whose derivatives up to order $k$ extend continuously to the boundary, and then keep track of the boundary terms that appear due to Stokes's theorem. In this case, $\Box_g$ will no longer be symmetric in general due to those. Of course, this is only one choice of domain - the problem you are studying may impose another choice.

Comment: Notice, however, that you can use Stokes's theorem only if the boundary of the region is at least locally Lipschitz.